# search into a website and result shows in iframe using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i have two input box and button. if i entered url in first text box and entered search text in second text box. Now i need results in iframe. I tried it but screen will be empty....

Here the code....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?php 
header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');
?>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


function Gsitesearch(curobj)
{
var domainroot=document.frm.domain.value;
var date=document.frm.opt.value;
curobj.q.value="site:"+domainroot+" "+curobj.qfront.value+" "+curobj.opt.value
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" id="frm" name="frm" target="myiframe" method="get" onsubmit="Gsitesearch(this)">
<center>
<h2>Search Tool Kit:</h2><br />
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
<tr><td><input name="q" type="hidden" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Domain Name:</b></td><td><input id="domain" type="text" style="width: 180px" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Search Word</b></td><td><input name="qfront" type="text" style="width: 180px" /></td><td><select name="opt"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" id="search" value="Search" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<iframe name="myiframe" style="width:550px; height:100px;"></iframe> 


</body>
</html>
```

Any body help me....

Comment: Define "won't work."  What does it do?  When you debug it, are the runtime values what you expect them to be?  Also, you've mentioned jQuery a couple of times, but you're not using jQuery here.  Is there other code as well?

Comment: ya, actually the search results not load in iframe... i need if code will be in jquery... thats it..

Comment: Note: search results should be show in iframe,

Comment: Problem seems to be with cross-origin policy. You need to use curl to get out from this

Comment: can u tell me how to implement curl...

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

**The HTML + Javascript:** (index.php)

```
<form id="myForm" >
    <input type="text" name="first" value="22" />
    <input type="text" name="second" value="" />
    <input type="button" value="See result on iframe" onclick="iframeResults()" />
</form>
<br/>
<iframe src="#" name="results"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
function iframeResults(){
    var
        form = document.getElementById("myForm"),
        first = form.elements.namedItem("first").value,
        second = form.elements.namedItem("second").value;
    if(first.length && second.length){
        window.results.location.href='results.php?first=' + first + '&second=' + second;
    }else{
        alert('Type some text on the two inputs before ;)');
    }
}
</script>
```

...and, finally...

**The PHP:** (results.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["first"]) && $_GET["first"] != "" && isset($_GET["second"]) && $_GET["second"] != ""){
    echo 'Received:<br/>
    First: '.$first.';<br/>
    Second: '.$second;
}else{
    echo 'Error! Type some text on the two inputs before. ;)';
}
?>
```

**Font:**

> *Me*

**Edit:** *does not work for cross-origin framing ;)*